# Remove ListView item highlight on tap Nativescript Angular + LineSeparator Color?

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript

It's December 2020 and people still get trouble to remove the highlight effect on `ListView` and `LineSeparator` causing by it.
I'm working with `Angular` + `Nativescript`.

This is the `iOS` workaround to remove tap highlight is this and it works:

```
onItemLoading(args: ItemEventData) {
    if (isIOS) {
        var cell = args.ios;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
  }
```

Android question: **How to do this with Android?** 
Android & iOS question: **How to remove the `SeparatorLine` color from `ListView`?**

This is my `tns-info`:

```
Getting NativeScript components versions information...
⚠ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 6.8.0 and the latest available version is 7.0.12.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 6.6.0-next-2020-05-08-112112-01 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 6.5.3 version and is up to date.
⚠ Update available for component tns-ios. Your current version is 6.5.2 and the latest available version is 6.5.3.
```

Many thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing the highlight/ripple on android, you can hook into the `loaded` event of the `Listview` and set some android properties like so:

```html
<ListView (loaded)="onLoaded($event)"></ListView>
```

```
declare const android;

onLoaded(event) {
  if (event.object.android) {
    event.object.android.setSelector(new android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable());
  }
}
```

For the separator color, you should be able to use the `separatorColor` property either directly in the html or through css:

```html
<ListView separatorColor="transparent"></ListView>
```

```css
ListView {
  separator-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: About `separatorColor`. This is the first way I've tried without success. All these methods don't work since I have installed the `RadDataForm` component... Seems this component also add separator lines all over the app...

Comment: Thanks for your reply about `Listview`. It's works. thanks.

Comment: Anyway I have opened an issue to Nativescript developers: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9116 this will helps everyone.
Thanks anyway for your help!